# Displacement on Particle Location

Tags: particles, shaders, displacement

I am trying to create a shader which uses displacement to create a dent in an object with a hair particle system, based on the locations of the hair particles.

The strawberry I have created is setup with hair particle system to render seeds around the model, and for extra effect I am trying to create a displacement dent effect around the locations of each particle emitted to show a sinking effect.

Strawberry

[image: Strawberry]

This is what I have so far, I'm fairly new to Blender! Thanks :)

Comment: Or would it possible to create a displacement modifier and set the seeds to only be spawned in the 'dented' vertexes?